# codeigniter running multiple functions concurrently

Tags: php, multithreading, function, codeigniter

I know PHP doesn't have any multi-threading, but I wonder if the following is possible.

I have 2 functions, let's call them login and doSomething and currently, I implemented them this way,

```
$member=$this->login();
$this->doSomething($member);
//show welcome page
```

When a user logs in, I want to do some stuff but it takes around 20 seconds or more to complete. Is there any ways where after login() is run, it will show the welcome page immediately while the method doSomething() is being executed separately. The method doSomething() doesn't return any values thus does not affect the welcome page.

Answer (score 2):

Ajax is your friend

[AJAX for Codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/AJAX_for_CodeIgniter)

[Nettuts+ AJAX & Codeigniter tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-8-ajax/)

[Ajax Tutorial](http://mrforbes.com/blog/2009/01/a-quick-code-igniter-and-jquery-ajax-tutorial/)

Comment: I'm agree with @TheShiftExchange. But really curious about actually "what" can make the server busy for 20 seconds during one user's request...